# Why can't I get the correct answer when using console.profile()?

Tags: javascript, firefox

I wonder how to use `console.profile()` in Firefox. I have read the following material http://getfirebug.com/wiki/index.php/Console.profile, I copied the code and run in my Firefox, but I did not see the result, why?

```
 function getById(id)
    {
        return document.getElementById(id);
    }

    function getViaSelector(id)
    {
        return document.querySelector(id);
    }

    var numberOfCalls = 10000;

    console.profile("getElementById() vs. querySelector()");
    for (var i=0; i<numberOfCalls; ++i)
        getById("test");
    for (var i=0; i<numberOfCalls; ++i)
        getViaSelector("test");
    console.profileEnd();
```

Comment: Well, is there an element with the ID test in your DOM?

Comment: it should be `document.querySelector('#'+id)`

Comment: there is already in my dom...

Comment: What else do you see when there is no result?

Comment: Did you look at the performance tab?

Answer (score 1):

Works for me if the page contains an element with id "test". The result is displayed on the run-time analysis tab of the builtin web console as expected.

Note, If you use Firebug the code-snippet needs to be loaded from a web server, as profiling of local files (injected code) is not supported by Firebug. Also make sure to enable script debugging which is disabled by default.

Here is a working example which you can either load from file or from a local web server (in both cases profiling works for me).

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Profiling Demo</title>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        function getById(id)
        {
            return document.getElementById(id);
        }

        function getViaSelector(id)
        {
            return document.querySelector(id);
        }

        var numberOfCalls = 10000;

        window.onload = function() {
            console.profile("getElementById() vs. querySelector()");
            for (var i=0; i<numberOfCalls; ++i) {
                getById("test");
            }
            for (var i=0; i<numberOfCalls; ++i) {
                getViaSelector("test");
            }
            console.profileEnd();
        }

    </script>
</head>
<body id="test">

</body>
</html>
```

The results appear in the Firebug Console. Unfortunately, I am not able to add a screenshot as my reputation is too low.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post - you can always comment on your own posts, and once you have sufficient [reputation](http://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](http://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment).

Comment: Thank you for your explanation. In absence of enough reputation I am not able to comment on questions though! Sorry about this.

Besides this I believe I have answered the question, i.e., what need to be done to use profiling in Firefox with web console or Firebug.

Answer (score 1):

The console does not have the data, the data is stored under the Performance Tab.

[image]